# Is it possible to customize the text in Menu items of Android ContextMenu?

Tags: android, text, menu, contextmenu, customization

In the project I'm working I need to show a context menu in some activities, where in addition to the item name we want to display some descriptive text about the action.

This implies having each menu item (possibly) show multiple lines of text, and for the descriptive text to be a different color than the title.

This is much better explained in the attached image.

[image: I want a menu item with Title + descriptive text]

I've done some reasearch before creating this question but couldn't find anything that works for this puspose. Thus any input on the matter, whether it's possible or not or how to accomplish it is more than welcome :)

Comment: please have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but the long answer is not easily. It will require digging into the Android source code a bit and doing a fair amount of research. It depends how important that extra text is.

If you're interested, check out [this blog post](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/android-how-can-you-implement-a-custom-menu-class/) (and the comments section of it) which sort of walks through some important parts of the source code. It doesn't specifically answer your question, but it should at least point you in the right direction to start looking.

One last possibility if you didn't want to do that but were desperate for something other than plain text would be to use the Menu icon property to display either a descriptive image rather than text, or an image which contains text. However, context menus do not support icons so you'd have to rethink your UI and whether or not that would cause a problem.

Sorry that this probably wasn't the kind of answer you were hoping for!

Comment: It wasnt the answer I hoped for but it was the one I expected. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Although I have not done this exact thing before, I'm pretty sure you could achieve this by inflating a customized menu XML which contains two separate text views within each element, that you could style however you'd like. For example, you would create this in a  `context_menu.xml`, and then do something like this...

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Read more about context menus on the Android dev site, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Comment: I have tried using this method however the menu item layout only allows for "title", could you elaborate a bit more on this idea?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't realize that the menu layout was so restrictive. I've added a new answer below, please check that out.